# Query czml/json data in smart way

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cesiumjs, czml

I am using Cesium and I have a czml file (very similar to JSON format) and I would like to identify one of its elements by specifying the tag of interest:

```
var czml = [{
    "id" : "document",
    "name" : "Basic CZML billboard and label",
    "version" : "1.0"
}, {
    "id" : "Point A",
    "name" : "Point A",
    "label" : {
        "fillColor" : {
            "rgba" : [255, 255, 255, 255]
        },
        "font" : "12pt Lucida Console",
        "text" : "Point A",
    },
    "position" : {
        "cartographicDegrees":[
            0, 0, 0
        ]
    }
}, {
    "id" : "Point B",
    "name" : "Point B",
    "label" : {
        "fillColor" : {
            "rgba" : [255, 255, 255, 255]
        },
        "font" : "12pt Lucida Console",
        "text" : "Point B",
    },
    "position" : {
        "cartographicDegrees":[
            10, 10, 0
        ]
    }
}];
```

My goal would be to access a specific element of the variable `czml` by been able to query the element. For example if I wanted to access the all the data of `point B` I would like to do it somehow with some function without using any loop possibly (My czml data could be very big!!!).

I was able to achieve my goal like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (czml[i].id === "Point B") {
        console.log(czml[i].id);
        console.log(czml[i].name);
        console.log(czml[i].label.text);
        console.log(czml[i].position.cartographicDegrees) ;      
    }
}
```

But as you can see this is very inefficient. What is a more elegant and efficient way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Did you really want to find the entry in the CZML raw data, or are you hoping to find a reference to the Cesium Entity that was created as a result of parsing this data?  (If the latter, it's: `dataSource.entities.getById('Point B');` )

Comment: Well I would like to do something like the answer proposed by Nathan P.; I tried to used the line you proposed by I get the following error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entities' of undefined` . What am I doing wrong? Could you maybe post your solution among the answers? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find) method.

```js
var czml = [{
  "id": "document",
  "name": "Basic CZML billboard and label",
  "version": "1.0"
}, {
  "id": "Point A",
  "name": "Point A",
  "label": {
    "fillColor": {
      "rgba": [255, 255, 255, 255]
    },
    "font": "12pt Lucida Console",
    "text": "Point A",
  },
  "position": {
    "cartographicDegrees": [
      0, 0, 0
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": "Point B",
  "name": "Point B",
  "label": {
    "fillColor": {
      "rgba": [255, 255, 255, 255]
    },
    "font": "12pt Lucida Console",
    "text": "Point B",
  },
  "position": {
    "cartographicDegrees": [
      10, 10, 0
    ]
  }
}];

var point = czml.find((e) => e.id === 'Point B');
console.log(point);
```

Comment: it seems to be great however when I run it in my code I get:  'e' is not defined... do you have any idea why?

Comment: Try this : `czml.find(function (e) { return e.id === 'Point B' };`, arrow functions aren't fully supported.

Comment: it tells me there is a missing semicolon somewhere and I guess also a parenthesis right?

Comment: Yes, there's a missing parenthesis after the curly brace.

Comment: also a semicolon before } ... anyways not it works better :) thanks